# Why we Add Meta_data in sqlite3

Tags: android, sqlite

I wants to know why we add the meta_data table in the sqlite3 database when that database is imported into the Android Application.
Create table meta_data(locale meta_data);
and inserting any value.
insert into meta_data(en_us);

So is there way to import database into application without declaring its Meta-Data

Comment: it is not the duplicate dear it is big difference between what and why?